# Access key value of dictionary in a clean way

Tags: c#, dictionary, key-value

I would appreciate, if there is a better way of how I can refactor the same code

Index.razor.cs:   -->
Method 1:

```
Result = (incomingValue > 5) ? null
                 : item.Id == Constants.ExampleDict.Keys.ElementAt(0) ? Constants.ExampleDict.Values.ElementAt(0)               
                 : Constants.ExampleDict.Values.ElementAt(2);
```

Method 2:

```
Result = (incomingValue > 5) ? null
                 : item.Id == Constants.ExampleDict.Keys.ElementAt(0) ? Constants.ExampleDict["Apple"] 
                 : Constants.ExampleDict["Banana"];
```

Thank you.

Comment: How do you define "better"? readibility? shorter? performance?

Comment: I would like to use dictionary in a property way. Shorter and more readable.

Comment: why do you use key-based storage like a `Dictionary`, when you want index-based access like `ElementAt`? That's contradictory. I think you can just use `Constants.ExampleDict.TryGetValue("Apple", out var value)` or `if(Constants.ExampleDict.ContainsKey("Apple")) // do something`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you already have key-value-pairs, why bothering about indices? That's cumbersome an may lead to strange behaviour, in particular as a `Dictionary` makes no guarantees about the order and thus about the elements at a specific *index*. However you can easily access the value for a specific *key* instead:

Easiest way is to use [`Dictionary<TKey, TResult>.ContainsKey(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey?view=net-7.0)

e.g.

```
if(Constants.ExampleDict.ContainsKey("Apple")) 
{
    var value = Constants.ExampleDict["Apple"]
    // do something with the value
}
```

Alternativly you can use this:

```
if(Constants.ExampleDict.TryGetValue("Apple", out var value))
{
    // do something with the value
}
```